# Is there a remote desktop application which supports multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

We mostly use Windows XP's "Remote Desktop Connection", but whenever we use it to connect to a computer with multiple monitors, even if the client computer has multiple monitors as well - the remote desktop only 'acts' as one monitor and we're forced to use half (or less!) of our available display area. Also - it completely changes the window arrangement on the second monitor.

Is there a remote desktop application that knows how to deal with this, or is this a problem inherent to Windows XP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RDC has supported multiple monitors since 6.0. There is a 6.0 update needed for XP machines which you can download [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876).

Simply type:

```
mstsc /span
```

at the command line while connected.

[This article](http://blog.tmcnet.com/blog/tom-keating/microsoft/remote-desktop-dual-monitor-support-tip.asp) is great for further information and tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

BTW if you want to actually have "seperate" remote monitors (having two or more screens rather than one giant one), the only solution I have found for this is [splitview](http://www.splitview.com/), which costs $39.  If anyone knows a cheaper solution, I would love to hear about it.